# Fill disabled input field in html by javascript and read it by servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I have a problem.
I have filled disabled input text fields by Jquery, but servlet cannot read it.  What's the problem?

```
<form action="buy" method="get">
    <fieldset>
            Total price: <input name="price" type="text" disabled id="tprice">
            <input id="sbm" type="submit" value="Pay">
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

JQuery

```
$("input[name='price']").val(5000);
```

Servlet

```
String price = request.getParameter("price");
System.out.println(price); // print null
```

Comment: Because its disabled, try readonly instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work with `disabled` field, try `readonly` instead.

Disabled fields are ignored completely as long as they are disabled. Read-only fields look like they can be edited (you can style this differently using CSS), but simply refuses any changes you try to make.